# How many HTML audio elements can I play at once?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have several audio clips on a web page that I want to play simultaneously, using JavaScript, via the `Audio()` class.

Is there a defined limit on the number of audio files that can play simultaneously? If not, is there a reasonable limit that I can expect most browsers to provide for?

As far as I can tell, the specification is silent on this matter.

Comment: I actually don't know the answer to this, but can't you find a way to "cheat" the browser to think you're calling the audio in different pages? What actually happens when you try to do it? Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: My ears aren't good enough to tell if any sounds are missing :) I'm trying to work out what the lowest common denominator is amongst browsers. I've noticed that a few JavaScript game engines seem to limit sounds to 10, but I suspect that it's arbitrary.

Comment: Although this doesn't replace the W3C reference, I found this. Hopefully it helps you get in the right direction: http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/

Comment: thanks, that's helpful

Answer (score 0):

No there is no definite limit, and the amount does not depend on the browser, but rather how many of the files it can load without timing out due to too many requests.